# AVDictionary set recorded file from stream metadata so video player does not think it is a stream

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I'm currently recording an RTSP stream using the FFMPEG libaries (essentially recording in 1 minute video files).  Everything is working well, with the exception that if I launch the video files, the player views them as streams, not as videos (so seeking is disabled, etc.).

I suspect I need to set the proper option when I am using `avformat_write_header(output_context, NULL)` instead of giving no options.

I've discovered the list of options in libavformat/options_table.h but none of them seem to apply.  As an example of how I'm thinking I need to solve this, I've looked at https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/libav-user/2013-January/003541.html and I see things like "sample_rate", "pixel_format" etc. that could be set.  Is there something to set the metadata in the file I'm writing from an RTSP stream to behave as a video instead of a stream when I play it after the fact?  Or if it isn't written with the header, is there some other way I can do this?

Comment: Can you provide a sample?

Comment: a sample recorded video segment?

Comment: Yes, if it's possible.

Comment: @tyb I've been trying to share one but I'm having trouble replicating the issue now.  I think it might be something specific with the video player vs the actual file itself.  I'm just going to close the question since it is beginning to seem like its not the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is related to the specific video player being used, which makes me believe its not related to the meta data but how the player is interpreting the video stream.

If it does turn out that I can explicitly set this using the FFMPEG libraries I'll mark that as the accepted answer.